# How to create bookmarks for Chrome browser using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, github, import, module

I'm using Python version 3.9.5. I would like to use Python to programmatically edit my bookmarks in my Chrome browser. In my research I came across this module that looks like it will do what I want:

> https://github.com/robperc/ChromeBookmarkEditor

I looked around and found [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) post that talks about how to install a package from Github. So, I ran this locally:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/robperc/ChromeBookmarkEditor@master
```

According to the readme on the repo, it says I can include this at the top of my file and it will import the module so that I can use it:

```
from ChromeBookmarkEditor import Chrome
```

but when I try to run my program I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ChromeBookmarkEditor'

Can anyone give me some tips as to how to properly import this module so I can use Python to edit my bookmarks for my Chrome browser? Or, if this isn't what I should be using to edit my bookmarks, can I please get some direction on how I should go about using Python to edit my Chrome bookmarks? As always, a correct, clearly explained answer will be accepted and upvoted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Copy the file `ChromeBookmarkEditor.py` to your current directory. 2) That package appears to be written for macOS. It references AppKit which is an Apple package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pip3 install chrome-bookmarks` and take a look at [this](https://pypi.org/project/chrome-bookmarks/) site